# How can I create an OSX-like list object with Java FX in Windows?

Tags: java, windows, javafx, awt

I can't find an object with the same look and feel like this one here:

[image]

It isn't an AWT List, nor a Swing ComboBox, so what is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a ChoiceBox.

```
ChoiceBox cb = new ChoiceBox(FXCollections.observableArrayList(
    "First", "Second", "Third")
);
```

[image]

- [ChoiceBox tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/user-interface-tutorial/choice-box.htm).
- [ChoiceBox javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ChoiceBox.html).

Comment: Thanks a lot, I wasn't aware of that one!